# I cant disable Proportional Editing

Tags: edit-mode, proportional-editing

So I was making a car, but I couldn't move a vertice. I saw that someone else had said this question and one person said to turn off proportional editing. But when I tried it wouldn't turn off. I unchecked the box that said proportional editing, but when I came back to make sure it was unchecked, it would still be checked. EDIt: It if off, but when i move any edge, vertice, or face it automatically turns on.

Comment: Have you tried hitting 'o' on the keyboard? That's the default shortcut to disable proportional editing

Comment: Yes, it but it doesnt work. Also tried Alt+O

Comment: I opened blender again, proportional editing is off, but when i   move the vertice, it turns on automatically

Comment: Interesting... I haven't had that problem, and it doesn't seem to come up a lot. There are a few similar bugs posted on developer.blender.org:

See https://developer.blender.org/T64019 and https://developer.blender.org/T64011

Comment: Same bug for me. Can't disable it

Answer (score 1):

Same here in Blender 3.0, *Proportional Editing* comes back automatically in object mode.

My workaround:
Go in *Edit Mode*, toggle *Proportional Editing* on and off.
Back to *Object Mode*, select one or two bones and *Proportional Editing* seems to work normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real culprit might be the *Mirror* option under the *Options* dropdown in each viewport.

I have no idea why it's sometimes turned on, maybe a cat walked on my keyboard. But when random vertices are moving when I don't want to, it's usually that. It needs to be turned off for every object individually.